# mount a share specifying options on mac

Tags: mount, osx, cifs

I would like to mount a share on a mac computer. On Linux I would write:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //${IP}/mydata ~/shares/myshare -o
uid=ubuntu,username=user,password=pass,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0664,
dir_mode=0775
```

This does not work on mac. So I tried:

```
sudo mount -t smbfs //user:pass@${IP}/mydata ~/shares/myshare
```

which works. However, I cannot make the -o option to work. How could I translate the linux options into mac compatible?